# Rails 4.1 Devise 3.3 column users.password does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to create a user manually through the console as such:

```
User.find_or_create_by(email: "user@mail.com", first_name: "Stan", last_name: "Smith", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", confirmed_at: Time.now)
```

I have done this many times in past projects but this time it's not working. It is not picking up the Devise password model attribute so this is the error I get:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.password does not exist
```

I have Rails 4.1.4 and Devise 3.3.0. Did something change in the latest versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `User.find_or_create_by` you should be using `User.create`.

Devise accepts a password and password confirmation on creation but the actual table only has a column called `encrypted_password`.

The "find" portion of `User.find_or_create_by` is looking for a column called "password" which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep you are right! It worked now :) Thanks. It used to work in Rails 4.0.2. I guess they changed something.

Comment: @AJGregory If accidentally creating/seeding multiple times, will this create multiple but same users? Coz I think the purpose of `find_or_create_by` is exactly to avoid that.

Comment: @wlnirvana that depends on a few things like if there are model validations in place to prevent duplicates. Otherwise, see Sharvy Ahmed's answer on this question for another approach.

Answer (score 16):

Still if you want to use [`find_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by), it accepts block:

```
User.find_or_create_by(email: "user@mail.com", first_name: "Stan", last_name: "Smith") do |user|
  user.password = "password"
  user.confirmed_at = Time.now
end
```

Comment: OMG this is exactly what I've been looking for for the last 18 month of Rails development! Thanks for sharing 
(for my money this should be the top answer)